# Having trouble making an outbox system

Tags: php, html, sms

I'm trying to make an message outbox system using php.
I'm trying to gather one messages from a database to a kind of outbox. I'm having an issue where it is giving me multiple results from the conversation instead of one like the facebook outlook.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM message WHERE toid='$touser'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $message = $row['message'];

    if ($touser >= 2) {

    }else{
?>
    <a href="message.php?msg=$user"><table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $fname." ".$lname;?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $message; ?></td><br/>
            <div id="line"></div>
        </tr>
    </table></a>
<?php
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, sounds great. Go for it! _( or did you have any question here? )_

Comment: Just not sure how i exactly display one result from the user i have retrieved the message from??

Comment: Sorry, please use the `edit` button below your question to add more information to it. There is no sense in adding it here in comments. Add this: _what_ exactly is it you want to achieve? _We_ cannot tell you how you want things to look. _What_ exactly is your issue with that? What is wrong with your code? _Be precise._ _Ask clear question one can answer._ Do not expect us to magically _guess_ what you might be looking for.